# Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service (MIM)

Tags: 2016, mim

MIM was installed on SharePoint 2016 server and it was working fine but suddenly stopped working. MIM was installed using Farm account and this account having full rights on server and Database server with DB owner and sysadmin rights:

1. Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service is stopped and when try to start it getting error in Event viewer:

   > Event ID: 6208:
   >
   > The server encryption keys could not be accessed.    User Action 
   >   Verify that the service account has permissions to the following
   >   registry key:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Forefront
   >   Identity Manager\2010\Synchronization Service    If the problem
   >   persists, run setup and restore the encryption keys from backup.
2. In System log error:

   > Event id: 7024: source: Service Control Manager
   >
   > The Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service service
   >   terminated with the following service-specific error:  %%2149781504
3. Whenever try to open miisclient.exe it gives error:

   > Unable to connect to the Synchronization Service and some possible
   >   reasons are:
   >
   > a.The service is not started.
   >   b.Your account is not a member of a required security group.

Please help how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your service account running the MIM service should have Full Control rights over the key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Forefront Identity Manager\2010`. Check and re-establish those rights, then attempt to start the MIM services.